# Removing Icon class when children count is 0

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

So here is my HTML Structure

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="icon">
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="internal">
     <div class="nochild"></div>
</div>
```

I'm creating a script that when the `nochild` has 0 child count because it's a ASP repeater, the fa-chevron-down icon should be removed, how do I do that if the `content` and `internal` class are asp repeaters?

Comment: what does it look like when it has children?

Comment: real solution is why are you outputting the element if the backend already knows there is no children? Add a simple .length check and add the element if it exists.